# Showing previous searches in PyCharm

Tags: eclipse, full-text-search, pycharm

Eclipse allows [viewing one's previous searches](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/images/view_search_previous.png) in one's search history even going so far as to show the exact state in which one left a previous search. For example, if one removed (i.e. excluded) a search result from a previous search, that previous search is shown without that search result when rerun via the Search History menu.

Does PyCharm have such a feature? If so, I would be quite grateful to learn how to enable it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *View* tool window is active (View -> Tool Windows -> Find (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>)) there's *Recent find usages* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) option in the context menu. It seems Pycharm does not remember excluded results, though.